CustomErrorHandler Not Catching Exceptions in Angular 18 New Build System
I have a custom error handler in my Angular 18 application that is supposed to catch unhandled exceptions thrown from the backend (ASP.NET). The implementation works fine in the Angular 18 browser build system, but it fails to catch exceptions in the new Angular 18 build system.
Here’s a simplified version of my CustomErrorHandler:
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private onUnhandledException = new Subject();
  onUnhandledException$ = this.onUnhandledException.asObservable();
  isErrorHandled = false;

  handleError(errorObj) {
    if (this.isErrorHandled) {
      return;
    }
    
    this.onUnhandledException.next(errorObj);
  }
}

In my Handler.service.ts, I subscribe to the onUnhandledException$ observable:
constructor(
  @Inject(ErrorHandler) private errorHandler: CustomErrorHandler,
  private zone: NgZone
) {
  this.errorHandler.onUnhandledException$.subscribe({
    next: (error) => {                
      this.shutdownApplication();
    }
  });
}

Issue:
When an exception is thrown from the backend, it correctly calls handleError() and emits the exceptions in the Angular 18 browser build system. However, in the new Angular 18 build system, the handleError() method does not seem to get triggered at all.
Questions:

What changes in the Angular 18 new build system could be affecting
the behavior of my custom error handler?
How can I ensure that unhandled exceptions are caught by CustomErrorHandler in the new
build system?
Are there any additional configurations or setup steps
needed for error handling in Angular 18 with the new build system?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I have also imported zone.js in main.ts file

The service is not even subscribed unless you import the service to the app component, could be due to tree shaking since you are not using the service.
You should simply import the service to the component and it should work fine.
...
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private handlerService: HandlerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    throw new Error('Thrown from AppComponent');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Alternative solution:
Since you are using a service you can simply just add the service through Dependency Injection and call the method directly, this will eliminate the timing issue.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HandlerService {
  constructor() {}

  shutdownApplication() {
    alert('shutdownApplication');
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
  onUnhandledException$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private handlerService: HandlerService) {
    super();
  }

  override handleError(error: Error) {
    this.handlerService.shutdownApplication();
    console.log('Via Custom Error Handler: ' + error.toString());
    // super.handleError(error);
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component, ErrorHandler, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HandlerService {
  constructor() {}

  shutdownApplication() {
    alert('shutdownApplication');
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
  onUnhandledException$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(private handlerService: HandlerService) {
    super();
  }

  override handleError(error: Error) {
    this.handlerService.shutdownApplication();
    console.log('Via Custom Error Handler: ' + error.toString());
    // super.handleError(error);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    throw new Error('Thrown from AppComponent');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: CustomErrorHandlerService,
    },
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo
